# Is it necessary to install mysql to save and retrieve sql data on another computer locally?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, local-storage

I have made an java application which utilises SQL database through MYSql . But I want to transfer that exe file to another computer. I want that the data is stored and can be accessed locally on that computer without installing Mysql on that computer through the Java application . Is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: the only option is to migrate your DB to some cloud server or your own server. But if you want to have this locally, it's not possible without installin mysql server.

Comment: The problem with cloud server is that I don't know how to connect the database then. I don't have much days to master it too. Secondly I don't have a server and It would be illogical to buy a new one for just a single client

Comment: Well I was just giving you the options. I don't know your requirements. 
You can always use H2 database, which doesn't require any server. But it depends on your needs.

Comment: Is it hard to learn and implement in Java application? Hz database

Comment: You don't need to learny anything. You just need to change properties file and dependency (if you are using spring-boot).

Comment: No I am currently using mysql database

Comment: Find tutorial how to connect Java with H2. It's nothing complicated. You just need to change your Java config from mysql to H2 + dependency.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install any Sql server and still want to save your sql data on your new computer, the answer is `no`. 
Your program needs to connect to a database server to CRUD your database. Java application could not do it by itself.

Comment: So which SQL server do you recommend?

Comment: A solution would be to embed a sqlite database, however this is not always applicable depending on the needs of the user

Comment: @SiddharthGolecha: Why not MySql? I think you use it in your Java application, right?

Comment: The user would then be a client. He wouldn't be manipulating data though

Comment: I understand your situation :). In this case, the best thing I think is that you should create an application client-server. 
If you save the data locally, users have a way to manipulate it then.

Comment: Yes , I used it in my application but I think installing mysql on client's computer is not a good option. I mean,  I can use mysql but it would be great if there is another alternative

Answer (score 1):

If you write your program to connect to MySQL, your users must connect to some MySQL server if you want it to run. So each user must either have their own copy of the MySQL server or connect to an existing shared one. So if that's the way your application works, you will have to install a MySQL server on each user's machine. (This is difficult to do in an integrated installer).

(A big selling point of DBMS systems is the sharing of data between multiple users on different machines.)

Other JDBC- and SQL- compliant database systems exist that run entirely within a Java application. Those database systems are single-user, but you can package their .jar files with the rest of your installer. The [H2 in-memory database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) is an open source example.  You may have to make some changes to your SQL to use an in-memory database, but you'll be able to use the same framework.

Some developers create programs with both standalone and shared modes. They do that by testing their programs both with MySQL (or some other database server) and their chosen in-memory database. If you do that, your users will be able to use personal, locally shared, or cloud-based data.

Of course, the users of shared or cloud-based data will have to know the JDBC connection strings for their servers. And you'll have to make sure they can put the connection strings they provide into the right properties file, when they "go shared".